# Datagridview doesn't properly scroll to bottom row when using DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, scroll

I'm using a WinForms DataGridView to display varying amounts of data. When using larger amounts I noticed that AutoSizing all cells results in inacceptable delays until the DataGridView is responsive(from a couple of seconds up to several minutes). Setting the DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode property to DisplayedCells rather than AllCells fixed that issue(3 minutes -> 5 seconds).

However now I'm experiencing problems automatically scrolling to the bottom of the DGV's contents.
I'm trying to achieve that by setting `dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv.RowCount - 1;`
which worked just fine before, but now it merely scrolls to one of the last rows and I have to manually click the scroll down button a couple of times until it actually displays the last row. Dragging the scroll bar to the bottom feels very wonky and takes a couple of drags to get to the last row.

I read somewhere else about setting the `dgvAnalysis.CurrentCell` to a cell in the desired row and also tried the following in the DGV's scroll event handler

```
private void dgv_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll)
        {
            dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
            dgv.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
        }
}
```

but neither seems to help. It seems that dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex is not set to the value I give for whatever reason.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix that or what I might've done wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  `DataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells` use the `DataGridView.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells)` method.

If the `DataGridView` content doesn't change after loading, then setting the `AutoSizeRowsMode` property is an overhead. In the form `Load` event or once the data binding is complete, call the `DataGridView.AutoResizeRows(DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells)` and the resizing will be done only once.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help me fix my problem. The resizing is basically fine as it is, it's just that it does not scroll to the bottom, since 'FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex' is not set to RowCount but a number lower than that.